# Save entire files using localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I would like to use `localStorage` to 'cache' some JS and CSS files in a web app that is primarily used on mobile devices (i.e., bandwidth restrictions). I'm thinking it would work something like this:

1. The page loads with a small `setup.js` containing code that checks `localStorage` to see if `bigScriptFile.js` has been stored previously.

   1. If it's not stored, `bigScriptFile.js` is downloaded and stored for the next visit.
   2. If it has been stored, then `bigScriptFiles.js` is read from `localStorage` and loaded/run as if it was downloaded like a normal file (i.e., `<script src="http://example.com/bigScriptFile.js"></script>`)

What I'm not sure how to do is step 1.1 -- storing the JS file. (I know that I can only store strings in `localStorage` and I know how to use `JSON.stringify()`.)

Surely it's not as simple as using escape():
`localStorage.setItem('bigScriptFile', escape('myJScode'))` to store, and
`unescape(localStorage.getItem['bigScriptFile'])` when retrieving

Even if it is that easy, how do I use JS to get the contents of bigScriptFile.js as a string? Perhaps by making an ajax call to a PHP script that returns the contents?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should rather put the correct cache headers on js files or look at the HTML5 [cache manifest](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html).

[W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html).

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the manifest only controls files in the browser cache. If the cache is cleared, then the files must be redownloaded. Since this app is primarily intended to run on iOS devices where, among other things, opened pages in Safari are sometimes flushed to reclaim memory, I'm looking for something more permanent. I realize this means I'll need a way to check that the `localStorage` version is out-of-date (and if so, deliberately download and store the new version) but that shouldn't be too hard. I'm more concerned with how to reliable store an entire JS file as a string

Comment: No, the files in the cache manifest is stored for offline/later usage.  You can close the browser and the only file thats being redownloaded is the cache manifest file. I reserve the right that I do not know how this is implemented in Safari to IOS

Comment: The cache manifest is intended for offline webapps -- if the manifest is changed then the browser has to validate all of the resources.  As long as your manifest isn't changed the files will all be kept alive, and your site will also work when the browser can't connect to the internet.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I guess I misunderstood cache manifest and that's probably the route I should go. I'd upvote Christian's answer but I don't have enough rep yet.

Answer (score 3):

Have you seen http://addyosmani.github.com/basket.js/ might work for what you intended to do